# Is it possible to set global settings for services in a docker compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to specify global settings for services in a Docker compose file?

For example, take this Docker Compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  test1:
    env_file: /path/to/env/file
    image: test
    container_name: test1
    ports:
      - "1234:22"
    networks:
      - dmz
    restart: always
  test2:
    env_file: /path/to/env/file
    image: test
    container_name: test2
    ports:
      - "2345:22"
    networks:
      - trust
    restart: always

networks:
  dmz:
    driver: bridge
  trust:
    driver: bridge
```

I don't want to have `env_file: /path/to/env/file` for every service and would like to make it apply to all services. I know I can pass it in the `docker-compose` command line but I'm hoping to do it from within the Docker compose file.

Comment: If you're holding your docker-compose files in the same directory, I believe you could take advantage of the fact stated in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) `By default, the docker-compose command will look for a file named .env in the directory you run the command.`
Also check out [this](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/210) github issue regarding this topic

Comment: Yup; aware of this. my `env_file` example was a sample. I'd like to do this with any/other setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [extensions as fragments](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#using-extensions-as-fragments).

> With the support for extension fields, Compose file can be written as follows to improve readability of reused fragments:

This is the example from the README.md:

```yaml
x-logging: &default-logging
  options:
    max-size: "12m"
    max-file: "5"
  driver: json-file

services:
  frontend:
    image: awesome/webapp
    logging: *default-logging
  backend:
    image: awesome/database
    logging: *default-logging
```

Answer (score 9):

Although @timsmelik's answer points in the right direction and shows how to use a yaml anchor and alias with scalar values, you can probably take advantage of the [merge key yaml feature](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) to set overridable default values for your services.

Here is an example to illustrate

```yaml
version: "3.9"

x-service_defaults: &service_defaults
  env_file: /path/to/env/file
  image: test
  restart: always

services:
  test1:
    << : *service_defaults
    container_name: test1
    ports:
      - "1234:22"
    networks:
      - dmz
  test2:
    << : *service_defaults
    container_name: test2
    ports:
      - "2345:22"
    networks:
      - trust
  test3:
    << : *service_defaults
    env_file: /some/override/env/file
    container_name: test3
    volumes:
      - /some/bind/dir:/whatever/target

networks:
  dmz:
    driver: bridge
  trust:
    driver: bridge
```

You can find a pretty good comprehensive explanation of all possible yaml anchor/alias usage applied to docker-compose files in [the following blog post](https://medium.com/@kinghuang/docker-compose-anchors-aliases-extensions-a1e4105d70bd)

Comment: Thank you! This also works great. I will play around with both and see which is better for my needs.